# sorl thumbnail migrate no effect

Tags: django, sorl-thumbnail

I wanna use `sorl.thumbnail` django app for generating thumbnails in my site.

I followed the guide and I added `sorl.thumbnail` to `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Also, I want to use the default key-value store, so I need to use the `migrate` command, but this doesn't do anything, it doesn't create the required database table. I tried the following commands, but it still does not create the tables:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py makemigrations sorl.thumbnail
python manage.py migrate
```

Whats going on? How can I migrate and add the required table in order to use default key-value store?

If I dont migrate the db it raises me a exception that says that the table `thumbnail_kvstore` wasn't found.

Comment: can you share errors ?

Comment: try `python manage.py migrate thumbnail`

Comment: You can also try `python manage.py showmigrations`. That will show which migrations have been applied.